# How to upgrade an PostgreSQL 8.3(32-bit)/ArcSDE 10.0 database to PostgreSQL 9.2(64-bit)/ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.2, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, migration

I need to upgrade a large production PG8.3(32-bit)/Arc10.0 database with a fair amount of programming (that has circular references) as-is.  This is a system that I inherited, so I don't have the usual knowledge/metadata about the system that I would normally have.

But the pg dump/restore are being impacted by the circular references (I understand that later pg_dump versions address this).  Apart from manually manipulating the plain text dump files, is there a better way to do this?  <strike>pg_upgrade perhaps (I'll be able to answer this one later today)?</strike>

And are there any gotchas on upgrading the sde repository? Helpful and/or clever tips?

Ideally, I need this to be mostly, if not totally automated (for the actual cutover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the newer pg_dump command line tools on your PostgreSQL 8.3 (you can run it from the 64-bit server and have it back up the 32-bit).  It's been a while since I've done that, but that often works better than using the older tool.

Comment: +1 although I didn't actually do it this way (I isolated 3 functions in public, and created a separate sql file to run after the restore).  Putting the correct st_geometry.dll in lib was my biggest problem. But I was able to use a 9.4 64-bit pg_dump to produce a back up file.